# Save the Response from HTTP to Blob Storage using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to save the response from the HTTP request(First Step) into the Blob Storage(Second Step) while using Azure Logic App.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, You can achieve it by using `Http` and `Create blob` task.
[image]

**Code**

```
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                "connectionName": "azureblob",
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/xxx/managedApis/azureblob"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_blob": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@triggerBody()",
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/testing",
                        "name": "Test",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Http"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

Just update your blob name with the expression like `utcNow('yyyyMMdd')`

[image]

Comment: is it possible to specify the name of the blob as the today's date?

Comment: @prateek yes it's possible. See my **update1** answer

Comment: That is great!.
I was looking to customize the HTTP url as well.. There are certain params like some token.. that needs to be passed in url dynamically.. Is that possible to configure that well ?

Comment: @prateek Could you post your query clearly with some example as a new question, because it may help others as well.

Comment: For `Create blob (v2)` this is not so straightforward; body of HTTP response is not available for Blob content.  Does anyone have a 2023 response for this?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have no extraordinary circumstances, yes, you for sure can save the Request content to a Blob.  Any Content really.

You will start with the Create Blob Action specifying the Trigger Body as the content.

Don't over think it, it's the same pattern as saving to a local file.